# Excel "if" formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an "if" formula that I need to duplicate for many columns, preferably without typing each if statement.  Formula is =if(k5>j5,0,j5-k5)  I have columns j through cy to include in the formula string.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you please share with us what you've tried so far to resolve this on your own? Have you done an Internet search for `copy excel formula across columns`?

Comment: You could also use "=min(0,j5-k5).

Answer (score 1):

If you're formula is referring to adjacent cells and and they are consistent then you should just be able to copy and paste the formula and it will adjust the formula itself as you move across the columns. ie. your first equation would be in cell J1 referring to cells J & K. Copy that equation and paste into cell K1 and the equation will adjust to refer to cells K & L and so on and so forth.